# Is there anyway to send protractor's output into a file?

Tags: node.js, testing, protractor, automated-tests, testlink

I'm looking for anyway to send protractor's terminal output into a file or a variable. I want to send it into a TestLink application's input.

Comment: Currently, how are you executing your tests (i.e. please paste command if that is how you are executing them)?

Comment: I am running it by 'protractor protractor.conf.js'.

Comment: In that case, I think that @DublinDev's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to send the output directly to another file from the command line

```
protractor .\conf.js > .\protractor.txt
```